# Is it alright to instantiate Similarity each time when using PerFieldSimilarityWrapper with Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I only initialize DiscogsSimilarity once when I start creating index, but because its a PerFieldSimilarityWrapper does that mean my code below instantiates a new Similarity class for each field indexed, and if so is that wrong ?

```
public class DiscogsSimilarity extends PerFieldSimilarityWrapper
{
    @Override
    public Similarity get(String fieldname)
    {
        if(fieldname.equals(ReleaseIndexField.TRACK))
        {
            return new MultipleJoinsSimilarity();
        }
        else if(fieldname.equals(ReleaseIndexField.ARTIST_NAME))
        {
            return new MultipleJoinsSimilarity();
        }
        else
        {
            return new DefaultSimilarity();
        }
    }
}
```

**Updated with solution based on answer**

```
public class DiscogsSimilarity extends PerFieldSimilarityWrapper
{
    private MultipleJoinsSimilarity mjs;
    private DefaultSimilarity       ds;

    public DiscogsSimilarity()
    {
        mjs = new MultipleJoinsSimilarity();
        ds  = new DefaultSimilarity();
    }
    @Override
    public Similarity get(String fieldname)
    {
        if(fieldname.equals(ReleaseIndexField.TRACK))
        {
            return mjs;
        }
        else if(fieldname.equals(ReleaseIndexField.ARTIST_NAME))
        {
            return mjs;
        }
        else
        {
            return ds;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short answer : yes 
Long answer, have a look at this code used by solr to instantiate it's similarity using the schema provided :

```
@Override
  public void init(SolrParams args) {
    super.init(args);
    similarity = new PerFieldSimilarityWrapper() {
      @Override
      public Similarity get(String name) {
        FieldType fieldType = core.getLatestSchema().getFieldTypeNoEx(name);
        if (fieldType == null) {
          return defaultSimilarity;
        } else {
          Similarity similarity = fieldType.getSimilarity();
          return similarity == null ? defaultSimilarity : similarity;
        }
      }
    };
  }
```